# How do I use innerHtml or appendChild() to add multiple rows to a table from an xdr call

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I make an xdr call to return data for a webpage, this includes table with some rows of data, I only retrieve a few rows so that it loads quickly, I then use

```
var data    = document.getElementById("data");
data.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

to replace the placeholder element with the data

Then I made  second call thats get all the data and it again replaces element called data with the full set. But this second call can retrieve alot of data and having problems rendering in one go, so now I want to make multiple calls just adding a modest amount of data to the existing table

*innerHtml* no good because replaces the current data
*appendChild()* not working for me because this is for adding one child element but I want to add multiple **tr** elements, i.e each async call will return data for 1000 rows e.g

```
<tr><td>Row1Col1</td><td>Row2Col2</td></tr><tr><td>Row2Col1</td><td>Row2Col2</td></tr>
```

What is a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `data.innerHTML += xhr.responseText`

Answer (score 0):

I d try make mutliple fetch requests and condition each following request on the response from the previous request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).